# Java - textField for loop not completing

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to make a 9x9 grid of textFields, where each textField is allocated to an element in a 2d array. For example the top left textField is field[0][0], the one right of that is field[1][0], and the bottom right textField is field[8][8].

So far I have

```
TextField[][] fields = new TextField[9][9]; {
    for (Y=0;Y<9;Y++) {
        XPosition=0;
        for (X=0;X<9;X++) {

                fields[X][Y] = new TextField(1);
                fields[X][Y].setColumns(1);
                fields[X][Y].setBounds(XPosition, YPosition ,32, 32);
                frame.getContentPane().add(fields[X][Y]);

                XPosition=XPosition+32;
            }
        YPosition = YPosition+32;
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run the program, only the first 5 textFields in the top row get created. I have a feeling all the other textFields are placed under the visible ones. The frame is definitely big enough, and I can't figure out any issues with the code.

Comment: What is your layout manager, can you simply use GridLayout ?

Comment: Or `GridBagLayout` or [`WrapLayout`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)

Comment: Also `TextField` is a heavy weight component, you might mean `JTextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a grid layout : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html
Absolute positioning is not reliable.

Comment: I've added frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,9)); which seems to have fixed it and sorted them into a 9x9 grid. How would I create a button outside the grid and also make the grid a definite size

Answer (score 0):

Adding 
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null); 
has fixed the error